# How to keep IP address of a pod static after pod dies

Tags: kubernetes, ip-address, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I am new to learning kubernetes, and I understand that pods have dynamic IP and require some other "service" resource to be attached to a pod to use the fixed IP address. What service do I require and what is the process of configuration & How does AWS-ECR fit into all this.

So if I have to communicate from a container of a pod to google.com, Can I assume my source as the IP address of the "service", if I have to establish a connection?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for example on Azure, this feature `[Feature Request] Pod Static IP` is under request:

See https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2189

Also, as I know, you can currently assign an existing IP adress to a load balancer service or an ingress controller

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip

> By default, the public IP address assigned to a load balancer resource
> created by an AKS cluster is only valid for the lifespan of that
> resource. If you delete the Kubernetes service, the associated load
> balancer and IP address are also deleted. If you want to assign a
> specific IP address or retain an IP address for redeployed Kubernetes
> services, you can create and use a static public IP address

Answer (score 0):

As you said we needs to define a service which selects all the required pods and then you would be sending requests to this service instead of the pods.
I would suggest you to go through this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types.

The type of service you need basically depends on the use-case.
I will give a small overview so you get an idea.

- Usually when pods only have internal requests ClusterIP is used
- Node port allow external requests but is basically used for testing and not for production cases
- If you also have requests coming from outside the cluster you would usually use load balancer
- Then there is another option for ingress

As for AWS-ECR, its basically a container registry where you store your docker images and pull from it.